# fixed thead with rowspan

Tags: css, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I have this table:
[image]
and I'd like to fix the thead like this:
[image]
but I get this:
[image]
here is my code:

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table th {
  background: #EEE;
  text-align: left;
}

.table th,
td {
  height: 30px;
}

.fixed_thead {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.fixed_thead tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixed_thead thead tr {
  display: block;
}

.fixed_thead th,
.fixed_thead td {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table fixed_thead" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan=2>cell</th>
      <th rowspan=2>cell</th>
      <th rowspan=2>cell</th>
      <th rowspan=2>cell</th>
      <th rowspan=2>cell</th>
      <th colspan=3 style="width:30%; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);">cell</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:33.33%;">cell</th>
      <th style="width:33.33%;">cell</th>
      <th style="width:33.33%;">cell</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because you change the trs to display block - therefore they are not table rows anymore

Comment: understood, so how can I achieve the table in the 2nd image? but with ths vertically aligned to tds

Comment: I've found the best way to do fixed headers is to use a js plugin (any css solutiuon usually results in misaligned headers or some other weird problems) - I usually go for [datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) as it does loads of other things like sorting and filtering too